# Why are these "sections"/ "boards" overlapping

Tags: html, css

I am building a website and I can get the two top sections to fit properly. They do when I am full screen but once I change the size of the screen it jumps down and leaves white space.

I have probably went about this whole thing the wrong way as a few other things seem not to work.

Here is the CSS:

```
/* This Resets All Styles */

* {
    hight: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


/*layout*/

p {
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 20px;
    position: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

/*boards*/

#board_1, #board_2, #boar_3, #board_4 {
    width: 100%;
}

#board_1 {
    background: url(../img/background_5.png);
    background-image: min-height: 750px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.board1_p {
    border-bottom: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding-left: 60%;
    padding-top: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

#board_2 {
    background-color: green;
    color: #333333;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 1000px;
    min-height: 1000px;
}
```

And here is the HTML-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Zack Reid</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <!--External Stlye-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <!--artical starts here-->
    <article>

        <!--header which holds the nav and title-->

        <section id="board_1" />
        <main>
            <div class="board1_p">
                <p>Hi, thats me over there. This is a my home well my Internet home, it has everything you want to know about me.</p>
            </div>

            </div>
            <header id="main_header">

                <div class="content">
                    <nav class="nav">

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#board_1" title="Home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#board_2" title="About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#board_3" title="Work">Work</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#board_4" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </nav>

                </div>

            </header>
            <!--header ends-->
            </section>

            <section id="board_2">
                <h2> About</h2>
                <p>Text is fixed 206 pixels from the top, while the background is moving 40 pixels to the left.</p>

            </section>

            <section id="board_3">
                <h2>Work</h2>
                <p>This is a selection of work that I have done some, on half is for clients the other is work I have done on my own time.</p>

            </section>

            <section id="board_4">

                <h2>Contact me if you have any</h2>

            </section>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

New HTML-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">


</head>

<body>
    <!--artical starts here-->

        <!--header which holds the nav and title-->

        <section id="board_1">

            <div class="board1_p">
                <p>Hi, thats me over there. This is a my home well my Internet home, it has everything you want to know about me.</p>
            </div>


            <!--header ends-->
            </section>



            <section id="board_2">
                <h2> About</h2>

             <header id="main_header">

                <div class="content">
                    <nav class="nav">

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#board_1" title="Home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#board_2" title="About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#board_3" title="Work">Work</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#board_4" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </nav>

                </div>

            </header>    


                <p>So You want to know about me</p>

            </section>

            <section id="board_3">
                <h2>Work</h2>
                <p>This is a selection of work that I have done some, on half is for clients the other is work I have done on my own time.</p>

            </section>

            <section id="board_4">

                <h2>Contact me if you have any</h2>

            </section>
</body>
</html>
```

New CSS-

```
/* This Resets All Styles */

* {
    hight: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


/*layout*/

p {
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 20px;
    position: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

/*boards*/

#board_1, #board_2, #boar_3, #board_4 {
    width: 100%;
}

#board_1 {
    background: url(../img/background_5.png);
    background-image: min-height: 750px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 1020px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.board1_p {
    border-bottom: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding-left: 60%;
    padding-top: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

#board_2 {
    background-color: green;
    color: #333333;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 1000px;
    min-height: 1000px;
}

 nav ul li
            {
             display: inline;
             margin: 10px;
            }

#board_3 {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #333333;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 1000px;
    min-height: 1000px;
}

#board_4 {
    background-color: red;
    color: #333333;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 1000px;
    min-height: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: FYI, a good IDE or a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is your friend. I saw many problems as soon as I pasted your code into Visual Studio to format it. I left the errors so that you could receive a proper answer; my point is that they are easy to find when using the right tools.

Comment: @TimMedora, Just FYI: Visual Studio (VS) appears to alpha-sort the properties within CSS. While good for projects within VS, re-ordering is not that great for editing already existing SO posts. Re-ordering CSS properties makes it significantly less convenient to compare changes between versions and/or questions to answers using the code prior to re-ordering. Using the SO snippet editor provides syntax highlighting (including errors such as were in the code here) and one button code formatting. It might be a good idea to point people at that first and then also say a full IDE is better.

Comment: Makyen - good to know. I wasn't sure how the snippet editor would do with malformed markup, but I just tried it and it seemed to do a good job formatting while preserving errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code. I saw a few mistakes:

1. in CSS, you've a `hight` property in * selector
2. in HTML, you've opened a `<main>`, closed a `<div>` and used `<section../>`

I've changed them. I've tried a few things on your code and I guess the problem is with your navigation. You're using `<div>`, `<nav>`, `<ul>`, and `<li>` tags for your menu. You have to position them to a fixed location or else they will overflow when browser size shrinks.

Here are the modified codes. I've gotten rid of your menu. Please check this if this is what you want. If so, try to find a way to fix menu's position.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Zack Reid</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <!--External Stlye-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css">
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <!--artical starts here-->
  <article>
    <!--header which holds the nav and title-->
    <section id="board_1">
      <div class="board1_p">
        <p>Hi, thats me over there. This is a my home well my Internet home, it has everything you want to know about me.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--header ends-->
    </section>

    <section id="board_2">
      <h2> About</h2>
      <p>Text is fixed 206 pixels from the top, while the background is moving 40 pixels to the left.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="board_3">
      <h2>Work</h2>
      <p>This is a selection of work that I have done some, on half is for clients the other is work I have done on my own time.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="board_4">
      <h2>Contact me if you have any</h2>
    </section>

  </article>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    /* This Resets All Styles */
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }
    /*layout*/
    p {
      line-height: 1.2em;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    body {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    h1 {
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 55px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    h2 {
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    h3 {
      font-weight: 400;
      font-style: italic;
      font-size: 22px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 5px 0;
      padding: 20px;
      z-index: 1;
      position: inherit;
    }
    /*boards*/
    #board_1, #board_2, #boar_3, #board_4 {
      width: 100%;
    }
    #board_1 {
      background: url(background_5.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100% auto;
      background-image: min-height: 750px;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .board1_p {
      max-width: 600px;
      padding-top: 25%;
      padding-left: 60%;
      color: white;
      font-size: 2em;
      border-bottom: 30px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #board_2 {
      background-color: green;
      color: #333333;
      min-height: 1000px;
      max-height: 1000px;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Check your links. BTW: I've changed the style link and background image.

**EDIT:**

New HTML code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stil.css" />

    <title>Zack Reid</title>
 </head>

<body>
    <!--artical starts here-->
    <article>

        <!--header which holds the nav and title-->

        <section id="board_1" />
        <main>

            <div class="board1_p">
                <p>Hi, thats me over there. This is a my home well my Internet home, it has everything you want to know about me.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <header id="main_header">

                <div class="content">
                    <nav class="nav">

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#board_1" title="Home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#board_2" title="About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#board_3" title="Work">Work</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#board_4" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </nav>

                </div>

            </header>
            <!--header ends-->
            </section>

            <section id="board_2">
                <h2> About</h2>
                <p>Text is fixed 206 pixels from the top, while the background is moving 40 pixels to the left.</p>

            </section>

            <section id="board_3">
                <h2>Work</h2>
                <p>This is a selection of work that I have done some, on half is for clients the other is work I have done on my own time.</p>

            </section>

            <section id="board_4">

                <h2>Contact me if you have any</h2>

            </section>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

New CSS. See that backgound-size:

```
/* This Resets All Styles */

* {
    hight: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


/*layout*/

p {
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 20px;
    position: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

/*boards*/

#board_1, #board_2, #boar_3, #board_4 {
    width: 100%;
}

#board_1 {
    background: url(s.jpg);
    min-height: 750px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 1020px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.board1_p {
    border-bottom: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding-left: 60%;
    padding-top: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

#board_2 {
    background-color: green;
    color: #333333;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 1000px;
    min-height: 1000px;
}

#board_3 {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #333333;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 1000px;
    min-height: 1000px;
}

#board_4 {
    background-color: red;
    color: #333333;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 1000px;
    min-height: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: @Makyen, Thank you so much, I knew there would be problems but I still cant see all them some how yet. Thank you again for the help and feed back :)

Comment: Also some how the p tag in the second board our in the third one for some reason now and the p tag in the third one is in the forth one for as well. I have looked good bit, it might just be you messing with me lol

Comment: I just used the code and the problem is still happening. See the first board when I make the page smaller a white space appears in between it and the second one. Thats what is really my big problem at the moment lol. The nav was still giving me trouble though so thanks for the help with that

Comment: Sezisli, Now all p tags are going into other sections, any help with that? It would be very appreciated

Comment: Hi again @ZackReid If you can create a fiddle for your question it'll be much easier for me to try and find a solution. When your browser window shrinks, all of the elements in page tries to fit in it. **Just saying** you can give each of your elements fixed height to prevent this kind of behaviour. With fixed height, you might need to use **overflow: none;** too. Like I said, create a fiddle and let's try to find out.

Comment: Sezisli here is the link for the fiddler-http://jsfiddle.net/zackreid/yLwzgmmo/1/. I am going to try again to get my head around whats going on and see if I can use what help you have given me all ready.. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi again Zack. I've changed one thing at your css. backgound-size property. I make it "cover". See my edited answer. I think this one works ;) BTW can you explain why you use <main> <section /> and a </div> I don't get that.

Comment: Well first thing is were do I find the changes that you made? lol

Comment: And I do not know why the main tag was there I couldnt find the closing tag for it so it might have been a mistake. Then for sections I used it as it allows you to break it up the way I want, I know you can use div to do that, which might work better but I don't really know lol. Then for the div tag I use it so I can control were certain things go on each board.

Comment: Look at #board_1 see  background-size: cover; I suggest you to fix your HTML code too. Try using w3 validator to see your mistakes. I like that tool ;)

Comment: Ahh that was me thinking you changed it in JSFiddle whoops :)

Comment: Hi so I ran the html through the validator and saw the mistakes that were there. I took some things out like the main tag, I don't even know why that was there :s and I removed the article tag as it wasn't serving any purpose I think ;)

Comment: But what about your white gap? background-size: cover; should solve it.

Comment: Oh yea sorry for leaving you in suspense ;) It fixed it but know I am looking to get he background to be responsive know lol.

Comment: Allright then. If this is solved your problem check this as answer. If not, let's wait for any other ideas.